# How to separate read db server and write db server on django 0.97?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, scalability

I am using Django 0.97 version with postgresql 9.0. I have configured hot streaming replication on a master db server and a slave db server. My application has heavy bot-driven writes on the DB and reads only from the users. So, it makes it very optimized if I make the read-access slave db for the users' and write-access master db for the bot write access. Unfortunately only Django 1.2 has multiple database support and its a huge effort to upgrade in my application.  I got some leads through the following link : http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/easy-multi-database-support-django/ However, this also requires me to change all instances of db access in my application. Is there any simpler way to assign separate db servers for read access and write access by fiddling with the the django core db module?

Comment: Predictably, you're going to have serious trouble getting any kind of help using a very new Postgresql feature with such an ancient version of Django...

Comment: There was never any such thing as Django 0.97. Presumably you're running off some unknown checkout between 0.96 and 1.0. Why can't you upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to upgrade to 1.2 as it will be significantly less work than hacking together features that already exist.  If you stick with 0.97 for much longer your life will only be more difficult down the road.

I'm guessing you may have some misconceptions on how using multiple DBs works in Django 1.2.  You do not have to "change all instances of db access in [your] application" if you use the [Database Routers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) feature of Django.

With a router, you can specify which database to use for reads and writes.  All of your existing django models should work and begin sending requests to the proper database.  It's pretty simple to set up a router, just check the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers).  All that is required is to create the router class, put it somewhere, then add a line in your settings.

It works really nicely and is not as much work as you may expect.  You may have other issues with upgrading that you aren't telling us, but as far as models go you shouldn't have many problems.